# SQL Inserting dups

Tags: sql-server

```
INSERT dbo.FileColumns(FileID,  RowID, ColumnID, Value)
SELECT FileID, RowID, ColumnID, Value FROM #TempFileColumns;
```

I have this index setup on the table dbo.FileColumns:
clustered, unique, primary key index on RowID, ColumnID

I get this error:
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_FileColumns'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.FileColumns'.

How to exclude such duplicates rows while inserting? Please help, thanks.

Comment: If you want all of the data then you simply do not insert the primary key if it's an autonumber or you do a MAX(Field)+1 if you need to find the next available ID.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide how you want to handle the duplicate records. One technique is to use a ROW_NUMBER with a partition to select the first record according to some business rule you define, like date or value order.

```
INSERT dbo.FileColumns(FileID,  RowID, ColumnID, Value)
    SELECT FileID, RowID, ColumnID, Value
    FROM (
      SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FileID ORDER BY RowID, ColumnID) AS RowNum,
        FileID,
        RowID, 
        ColumnID,
        Value 
      FROM #TempFileColumns) T
    WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Other techniques may be to see why you get duplicate file ids when generating your temp table (maybe a bug somewhere in there), or using aggregates to get the unique fileids (which doesn't seem to fit this scenario).

Answer (score 0):

One possible (already-mentioned) method would be to not insert the ID, and allow the table to handle the key generation (assuming that you have FileID set up as an IDENTITY column):

```
INSERT dbo.FileColumns(RowID, ColumnID, Value)
SELECT RowID, ColumnID, Value 
FROM #TempFileColumns;
```

Another method, if you are working with data that might already be in the table, would be to check the destination first to make sure you haven't already loaded it:

```
INSERT dbo.FileColumns(FileID,  RowID, ColumnID, Value)
SELECT FileID, RowID, ColumnID, Value 
FROM #TempFileColumns tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.FileColumns tbl
    WHERE tbl.FileID = tmp.FileID

  )
```